# Error while installing GETOPT::LONG perl module

Tags: perl, module, long-integer, getopt, installation

I am trying to install getopt::long . however, I am getting the below error. Is there a way to manually remove the files and where can I find which files need to be removed.

```
C:\Users\sastagi\Desktop\Getopt-Long-2.42>perl Makefile.pl
Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)

I found left-over files from a previous version of Getopt::Long.
These should be removed.
I can add instructions to the Makefile to remove them when you
install this version.
Shall I add the remove instructions?  y
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Getopt::Long
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
```

Comment: Have you tried running make? It sounds like the Perl script has created what you need.

Comment: Try running `make -n` it will show you what the makefile will do without running it.  You should be able to find the rm commands in the output.

Comment: You told it that it should remove the files when you do `make install`. That's not good enough?